# How to start bluepill on your VPS(Digital Ocean)?

Tags: bluepill

```
discourse@fyps:~$ bluepill stop 
Error: There are no running bluepill daemons. 
To start a bluepill daemon, use: bluepill load  
discourse@fyps:~$ bluepill load 
/home/discourse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bluepill-0.0.66/bin/bluepill:108:in `exists?': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
from /home/discourse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bluepill-0.0.66/bin/bluepill:108:in `'
from /home/discourse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bluepill:23:in `load'
from /home/discourse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bluepill:23:in `'
from /home/discourse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/discourse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
```

I want to know how can I start bluepill,Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i do like so:

```
$ /usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_bluepill --no-privileged stop
$ /usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_bluepill --no-privileged quit
$ RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000 RAILS_ROOT=/var/www/discourse RAILS_ENV=production NUM_WEBS=2 /usr/local/rvm/bin/bootup_bluepill --no-privileged -c ~/.bluepill load /var/www/discourse/config/discourse.pill
```

last command you can get from output of this command:

```
$ crontab -l
```

this would work if you installed discourse using [INSTALL-ubuntu.md](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-ubuntu.md)